# ¿php://input no me retorna datos para el webhook sera porque lo tengo en https, que puedo hacer?

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-api, webhook

Estoy usando el `webhook` de *facebook messenger*, para un chat bot pero el bot no responde el mensaje, porque no le llega el **id** del sender, el cual es recolectado por el `php://input` pero por alguna extraña razón no me funciona, no sé qué puedo hacer, cabe decir que lo estoy haciendo con laravel.

```
public function index()
    {

        $local_token = env('FACEBOOK_MESSENGER_WEBHOOK_TOKEN', 'facebook_messenger_api');

        $hub_verify_token = request('hub_verify_token');

        if ($hub_verify_token == $local_token) {
            echo request('hub_challenge');
            exit;
        }
        try {
            $JSONData = file_get_contents("php://input");
            $dataObject = json_decode($JSONData);

            $sender = $dataObject['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];

            session(['idSender' => $sender]);
            $idSender = session('idSender');

            $token = env('PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN', '!!');
            $bot = new FbBotApp($token);
            $text = 'Hi Buddy';
            $recipient = $idSender;

            $message = new Message($recipient, $text);
            $bot->send($message);
            print_r($_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true));
        } catch (Exception $th) {
            echo $th;
        }
        return $message->getData();

    }
```

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($dataObject);` para revisar si el dato está o no en el objeto.

Comment: Hice una búsqueda rápida y encontré este [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup/), si es eso lo que estas haciendo - Que es lo que has hecho de ahí hasta ahora? - Y, a que te refieres con "sera porque lo tengo en https"? Ahí dice "**SSL obligatorio** El webhook se debe implementar en un servidor con un certificado SSL válido, de manera que pueda aceptar solicitudes en HTTPS.", o sea, trabajando en localhost no va a funcionar si no usas glicht u otro servicio similar que te provea una url publica https.

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, estaba mal referenciada la variable $sender tenia que ir así, $sender = $dataObject->entry[0]->messaging[0]->sender->id; dada a la estructura del json que retornaba el webhook de facebook, por si les interesa utilizo un host virtual llamado ngrok

Comment: Si te animas, escribe una respuesta de como lo resolviste, así queda registrado y le puede servir a otros

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude solucionar, estaba mal referenciada la variable $sender tenia que ir así, $sender = $dataObject->entry[0]->messaging[0]->sender->id; dada a la estructura del json que retornaba el webhook de facebook, por si les interesa utilizo un host virtual llamado ngrok